# Way of Thinking for Solving Geometric Distributions

Tags: probability

So the textbook used a different method to solve this question than I did and I don't think I would reproduce it if given another similar question without knowing when to use their method.

Question:

> Bill, Mary, and Tom have coins with respective probabilities $p_1, p_2, p_3$ of turning up heads. They toss their coins independently at the same time.
>
> What is the probability that the first person to get a head has to toss exactly $n$ times?

[image]

As you can see, the textbook answer is much simplier and easier to calculate, although the logic is not as easy to come up with.

And why not use the equivalent difference of $P($first person to get a head toss less than $n+1$ times$)-P(...$first person to get a head toss less than $n$ times$)$? **How do you instinctively determine which method is easier without writing all of them out? (no time to do that on exams)**

Comment: > By solving a lot of problems.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar  Yes, but say you see this question and you know both methods can solve it. How do you determine which one to use?

Comment: whats the title of the book Abacus ? I agree with @PiyushDivyanakar

Comment: @Isham Probability by Jim Pitman. The solutions have no steps. Ugh! Horrible.

Comment: Lol I see what you means...had some books of that kind

Comment: Pitman's book is difficult in places, but wonderfully insightful throughout. Consider yourself fortunate to be using it. Well worth the effort to stick with it.

Comment: Using "P(First person tosses fewer than n+1 times)...etc."...I guess it works but if you try this it gets messy (and this is a simple example--suppose there were ten people?). The "more than" formulation exploits the simple probability $(1-p_i)^n$. But also I was wondering why they fail to account for ties?

Comment: @daniel Interesting. So for geometric distributions, the probability of more than something generally gives a simplier formula than $=$ and $<$?

Comment: Maybe not, just that in general if P(A) is hard to calculate P(~A) = 1- P(A) may offer an easier route.